# How to change font color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want make it so when the menu is selected outside the white borders the font color of the letter changes to black instead of white, I tried to change it but I couldn't, if someone takes a look at the code would know where to put the adjustment?

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: controller.items.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    final _item = controller.items[index];
    if(_item['rota'] == Routes.home){
      return Obx(() => Container(
        decoration: (controller.selectedIndex == index)
            ? const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.white),
                bottom: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
            : null,
        child: Obx(() =>  Card(
          color: const Color(0XFF007E94),
          elevation: 3,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              _item['titulo'],
              style: const TextStyle(color: (controller.selectedIndex == index ) ? Colors.black :  Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: _item['icone'],
              onTap: () {
                controller.selectedIndex = index ;
                Get.toNamed(_item['rota']);
              },
              selected: controller.selectedIndex == index
          ),
        )),
      ));
    }
  }
),
```

I tried this way but still can't adjust

[image]

Comment: Try to remove `const` keyword on line no *59*

Comment: See my below answer in details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, remove `const` keyword for `TextStyle`

```
title: Text(
              _item['titulo'],
              style: TextStyle(color: (controller.selectedIndex == index ) ? Colors.black :  Colors.white),
            ),
```